# Why does this example of pointer dereferencing work?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, casting

I have some code, and it works, and I don't understand why. Here:

```c
// This structure keeps the array and its bookkeeping details together.
typedef struct {
    void** headOfArray;
    size_t numberUsed;
    size_t currentSize;
} GrowingArray;

// This function malloc()'s an empty array and returns a struct containing it and its bookkeeping details.
GrowingArray createGrowingArray(int startingSize) { ... }

// Self-explanatory
void appendToGrowingArray(GrowingArray* growingArray, void* itemToAppend) { ... }

// This function realloc()'s an array, causing it to double in size.
void growGrowingArray(GrowingArray* arrayToGrow) { ... }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    GrowingArray testArray = createGrowingArray(5);

    int* testInteger = (int*) malloc(1);
    *testInteger = 4;

    int* anotherInteger = (int*) malloc(1);
    *anotherInteger = 6;

    appendToGrowingArray(&testArray, &testInteger);
    appendToGrowingArray(&testArray, &anotherInteger);

    printf("%llx\n", **(int**)(testArray.headOfArray[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

So far, everything works exactly as I intend. The part that confuses me is this line:

```c
printf("%llx\n", **(int**)(testArray.headOfArray[1]));
```

By my understanding, the second argument to printf() doesn't make sense. I got to mostly by trial and error. It reads to me as though I'm saying that the second element of the array of pointers in the struct is a pointer to a pointer to an int. It's not. It's just a pointer to an int.

What *does* make sense to me is this:

```c
*(int*)(testArray.headOfArray[1])
```

It's my understanding that the second element of the array of pointers contained in the struct will be fetched by the last parenthetical, and that I then cast it as a pointer to an integer and then dereference that pointer.

What's wrong with my understanding? How is the compiler interpreting this?

Comment: Your design is wrong. `headOfArray` should be `void*`. You should also call `appendToGrowingArray(&testArray, testInteger);` not `appendToGrowingArray(&testArray, &testInteger);`

Comment: `*testInteger = 4;` writes out of bounds, you only allocated 1 byte

Comment: `**(int**)(testArray.headOfArray[1])` is probably undefined behaviour, and also you used the wrong printf format specifier.  To get better answers post a MCVE, there are a lot of unknowns in the code you didn't post which affect the question

Comment: Why do you think it is a pointer to an int?? You added `&anotherInteger` to the array. `anotherInteger` is a pointer to an integer so `&anotherInteger` is a pointer to a pointer to an int.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your `appendToGrowingArray` looks something like this:

```
void appendToGrowingArray(GrowingArray* growingArray, void* itemToAppend) {
    growingArray->headOfArray[growingArray->numberUsed++] = itemToAppend;
}
```

though obviously with additional logic to actually grow the arrow.  However the point is that the `itemToAppend` is stored in the array pointed to by `headOfArray`.

But, if you look at your `appendToGrowingArray` calls, you are passing the **addresses** of `testInteger` and `anotherInteger` -- these are already pointers to integers, so you are storing pointers to pointers to integers in your `headOfArray` when you really intend to store pointers to integers.

So, when you consider `testArray.headOfArray[1]`, it's value is the *address* on `main`'s stack of the variable `anotherInteger`.  When you dereference it the first time, it now points to the address of the buffer returned by the second `malloc` call that you stored in `anotherInteger`.  So, it's only when you deference it a second time that you get to the *contents* of that buffer, namely the number 6.

You probably want to write:

```
appendToGrowingArray(&testArray, testInteger);
appendToGrowingArray(&testArray, anotherInteger);
```

instead.

(As noted in a comment, you also should fix your mallocs; you need more than 1 byte to store an integer these days!)